# Generate NPM package from Swagger documentation

Tags: node.js, npm, client, swagger

We have build a NodeJs serveur, and we have a SwaggerDocumentation

But, we would like to generate a NPM library client from our SwaggerDocumentation

For have a library available for others NodeJS project
There is maybe somewhere a swagger-codegen node for client?

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Swagger Codegen includes a JavaScript client generator. This client includes `package.json` and can be [published to npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry).